# Simple CNG example besides the one on Microsoft's site?

Tags: windows, cryptoapi, cng

I've cowered the Internet, looking for a way to simply use CNG with SALT/IV. I've gone over this example [Microsoft CNG Sample Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccng/encrypting-data-with-cng), but I can't figure out all the `rgb*` entries, and the sample data it defines to encrypt is never used! Oy vey...Is there just a "simple" sample that shows how to encrypt/decrypt with an IV using CNG?

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16465/Product-Keys-Based-on-the-Advanced-Encryption-Stan See this thread. Hope it helpful.